# onItemClick for custom ArrayAdapter - with recycled views

Tags: android, listview, onitemclick

Does anyone have a good tutorial for implementing `onItemClick()` for a `ListView` populated by a custom `ArrayAdapter`?

I'm struggling with how Android is recycling views, and how to affect the layout of the selected view (which is a `RelativeLayout`). The way I've implemented it, I'm just doing a simple background colour change, but everytime I choose a row, when I scroll the `ListView` there are other off screen items selected too.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please take a look at this tutorial for custom listview in android. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11693838/787375) answer. Custom code of `ArrayAdapter.getView()` (where view recycling is done) might be useful to you, I was trying to achieve something similar and it worked for me at last :)

Comment: Good answer! Can you post (or send me) your onItemClick for setting the Event to "checked"? I just want to see how it compares to mine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find lots of good examples of the custom Listview with Adapters.Some of the Examples are listed below:

(1)[custom-listview-android](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html)

(2)[android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

(3)[Custom Array Adapter](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/)

Comment: Cheers for that. I'll take a look at those and see if any of them help. I see they all assume that the Activity being used is ListActivity, not sure this makes a difference, but mine is just an Activity comprised of various views, 2 of which are ListViews. Thanks though, I'll revert if these help.